# PHP page doesn't load. Instead it gives me a 404 error

Tags: php, windows, apache

The title describes the question.

I have PHP installed, Apache, MySQL and also phpMyAdmin in the htdocs folder of Apache. I installed them separately and do not use a compilation package. I did try to create a php file with phpinfo

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

Saved the file as phpinfo.php

When going to

```
http://localhost
```

I see the phpinfo.php file listed. When I click the phpinfo.php file

I get a 404 error. There are no other files listed in the root http folder except one (phpinfo.php)

PHP was installed and php short tags are enabled

```
short_open_tag = On
```

I am not sure if it's a capital On or on

Note: I used http://www.jesterwebster.com/setting-up-a-test-bench-web-server-with-apache-php-mysql-and-more-on-windows/26 as a guide for my Apache and PHP install

I opened the error log and I found something disturbing. Not sure how to fix it

```
[Fri Aug 03 13:07:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/website/example/online/Program Files, referer: http://localhost/
[Fri Aug 03 13:09:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/website/example/online/Program Files, referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: Try moving that file to a different folder within the htdocs directory and then accessing it. E.g. Wwwroot

Comment: The short_open_tag config setting has nothing to do with your code above. It would only matter if you did <? phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: You obviously have the file in the wrong spot. Try to see where it belongs.

Comment: Have you actually started up Apache?

Comment: if it was the `short_open_tag` you would get a 500 error. Stupid question, but have you tried going to `localhost/phpinfo.php`

Comment: You should also not allow users to view the index of a folder if they don't enter a filename. [Article here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/).

Comment: @Matt i just setup a Windows box with Apache and PHP. I was testing if PHP was installed correctly. I used the Installer to install PHP

Comment: @mlishn I did try going to the file directly. I got the 404 error. I know it is in the correct directory because it will display any HTM file. It won't load any PHP file

Comment: That's awesome! If your server started up with PHP added to it, your installation went fine, so it's not PHP. A 404 is thrown when your server cannot find the file. If it's showing up in your index, you shouldn't be getting a 404 error.

Comment: What do you have set for your DocumentRoot?  Actually, can you just post your .htaccess file, or httpd.conf file?

Comment: I set it to DocumentRoot "C:/websites/example/online" (as per the documentation that I linked above)

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation you linked above, and the thing is, the place where your file is located, is not the same as the DocumentRoot.

Comment: I fixed the typo. I'll upload the httpd.conf file but getting a 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your error logs, your DocumentRoot "C:/websites/example/online"  is websiteS, your error log is looking for website without the s.

Comment: Good eyes :).  Sometimes the best way to figure this out is to literally copy and paste the log information and the configuration information above one another in a text editor to see the difference.  I do it all the time when I have issues like this.  Very easy to see the missing 'S' that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed from apache configuration file that PHP is enabled and is configured correctly to work with apache? And has the apache server been restarted after configuration? Also Try adding an html file in the htdocs directory to confirm if the directory is correct.

Edit:  Also you mentioned that error log is looking for your file in  this directory
C:/website/example/online/Program Files

But you mentioned that you placed phpinfo.php in htdocs folder for apache. There might be an issue related to difference between those two paths

Comment: This isn't an issue with PHP being enabled, if it were not it would display the text of the PHP file.  It's the path settings that are jacked.